# how to execute a command for all .dat files in a directory

Tags: python, numpy

I want to be able to execute these few simple commands for all .dat files within a directory. So it will print out all of the maximum values from each file, i just cant figure out how to do it.

```
dr='/home/data/'
image='*.dat'
b=np.genfromtxt(dr+image).T[1] #luminsity

q=getmax(b)
print 'max b=', q
```

Comment: The code you have posted... doesn't really attempt to solve the problem. Is that really all you have tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`glob.glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) (or [`glob.iglob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob)) to get `*.dat` files in `/home/data`:

```
import glob

for filepath in glob.glob('/home/data/*.dat'):
    b = np.genfromtxt(filepath).T[1] #luminsity
    q = getmax(b)
    print filename, 'max b=', q
```